# Createfile2, ReadFile, and WriteFile; why isn't ReadFile reading what I've written in WriteFile?

Tags: c++, .net, file-io, createfile

For testing and to make sure I've got everything down so that I can start scaling things up later, I'm trying to create a file handle, write a given buffer of bytes to that file handle, then read part of that file into a new testing buffer.

I have the code:

```
const size_t vSize = 0x10000;

std::vector<byte> buffer(vSize, 0);

for (int i = 0; i != vSize; ++i)
{
    buffer[i] = i & 0xff;
}

std::wstring path = ApplicationData::Current->LocalFolder->Path->Data();

std::wstring testFileName = path + std::wstring(L"\\TestVariablySized");

_CREATEFILE2_EXTENDED_PARAMETERS extend = { 0 };
extend.dwSize = sizeof(CREATEFILE2_EXTENDED_PARAMETERS);
extend.dwFileAttributes = FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL;
extend.dwFileFlags = FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING;
extend.dwSecurityQosFlags = SECURITY_ANONYMOUS;
extend.lpSecurityAttributes = nullptr;
extend.hTemplateFile = nullptr;

HANDLE hMappedFile = CreateFile2(
    testFileName.c_str(),
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
    0,
    OPEN_ALWAYS,
    &extend);

_OVERLAPPED positionalData;
positionalData.Offset = 0;
positionalData.OffsetHigh = 0;
positionalData.hEvent = 0;

WriteFile(
    hMappedFile,
    &buffer[0],
    vSize,
    NULL,
    positionalData);

std::vector<byte> testBuffer(128);

ReadFile(
    hMappedFile,
    (LPVOID)&testBuffer[0],
    128,
    NULL,
    &positionalData);
```

Unfortunately, when I set a breakpoint after and check to see what's actually in testBuffer, I find that it's all zeroes.  I've also tried all of the above without positionalData (i.e. replacing it with NULL in the calls to WriteFile/ReadFile), but that doesn't change the outcome.  Similarly, I've tried this with NULL in place of the extended parameters for CreateFile2, same result.

I will eventually want to be able to choose an arbitrary location in a given file to read bytes from, so if I'm doing something weird with positionalData, please let me know.

As of right now, I don't know whether the problem is in CreateFile2, ReadFile, WriteFile, or some combination thereof.  Your help is greatly appreciated!

edit: It turns out that ReadFile() is returning False, and the last error code after is 0x57 (87)--ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER.  Currently googling around on that, but in the event that I can't quite get the answer, I'm still interested in reading suggestions.  It's not immediately obvious to me what I did wrong here, but my first guess is that I made a mistake with positionalData somehow.

final edit: removing FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING did the job at the end.  Thank you!

Comment: `ReadFile()` returns a BOOL indicating success or error. Check if it's FALSE, and if so call `GetLastError()` to find the error code.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  ReadFile() was indeed returning false, and it gives me the error code 0x57 (87).  Googling around on that right now.

Comment: Error 87 is `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`.  `ReadFile()` is failing because you are not following the [restrictions imposed by the `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` flag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc644950.aspx). If you get rid of that flag, then the code would likely work. Otherwise, update the code to follow the rules correctly.

Comment: You are correct, removing the FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING made it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass an `OVERLAPPED` structure to `WriteFile()`/`ReadFile()` when using a *synchronous* file handle, the functions will write/read bytes at the starting file offset specified by the `OVERLAPPED`, and then update the `OVERLAPPED` to contain the new file offset *after* the bytes that were written/read.  You are passing the same `OVERLAPPED` to both `WriteFile()` and `ReadFile()`, but you are not rewinding the `OVERLAPPED`'s offset before passing it to `ReadFile()`, so `ReadFile()` does not read the bytes that were previously written.

```
ULARGE_INTEGER ulOffset;
...

ulOffset.QuadPart = 0; // or whatever offset you need
positionalData.Offset = ulOffset.LowPart;
positionalData.OffsetHigh = ulOffset.HighPart;
WriteFile(hMappedFile, ..., &positionalData);

...

ulOffset.QuadPart = 0; // or whatever offset you need
positionalData.Offset = ulOffset.LowPart;
positionalData.OffsetHigh = ulOffset.HighPart;
ReadFile(hMappedFile, ..., &positionalData);
```

When you pass NULL instead of an `OVERLAPPED` structure, the functions will write/read bytes starting at the current file offset stored within the file handle itself, and then update the handle to store the new file offset *after* the bytes that were written/read.  So, if you are using the same file handle for writing and reading, you will have to rewind the file handle's current offset using [`SetFilePointer()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365541.aspx) or [`SetFilePointerEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365542.aspx):

```
LARGE_INTEGER liOffset;
...

liOffset.QuadPart = 0; // or whatever offset you need
SetFilePointerEx(hMappedFile, liOffset, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);
WriteFile(hMappedFile, ..., NULL);

...

liOffset.QuadPart = 0; // or whatever offset you need
SetFilePointerEx(hMappedFile, liOffset, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);
ReadFile(hMappedFile, ..., NULL);
```

That being said, you are opening the file with the `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` flag, which has *very tight restrictions* on what file offsets, buffer addresses, and buffer sizes can be during file I/O operations.  Read the MSDN documentation for details about the specific rules you must follow when using that flag:

[File Buffering](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc644950.aspx)

Comment: Educational, thanks.  However, the issue I'm experiencing still persists, even after resetting positionalData.Offset to 0 after writing.

Comment: Marking yours as correct, as this was at least half of getting it to work.  The other half was the last comment you left up top.  Edit: Now this is the complete answer after your edit.